# Compile Sources in Xcode has a wrong path associated

Tags: ios

I recently renamed my Xcode application and did all the changes required in Xcode settings. I manually renamed the folders. But now when I run the application, build fails. Error I get is no files found by clang. In the Build Phases, under Compile sources, the file path shown is "New_project_Name/Old_project_Name/New_project_Name/file.m" whereas it should be "New_project_Name/New_project_Name/file.m"

I have searched for many different solutions/workarounds & none have helped till now.

Comment: I would delete all the (references) to the source files and re-add them.